# show hide contents on click of linkable column's data in a dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a column in a dataTable which is linkable. I need to retrieve the row data and to show the contents of a different tab on click of the linkable column's data using javascript/jquery. Please help me with some examples.

Thank You.

this is my html table

```
                       <thead>
                       <tr class="headtable">
                           <th>Product Name</th>
                           <th>category</th>
                           <th>Serial Number</th>
                       </tr>
                       </thead>
               <tbody>

                <tr>
                   <td>xxxx</td>
                   <td>yyyy</td>
                   <td><a href="#" id="link1">zzzz</a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <td>xxxx1</td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td><a href="#" id="link2">zzzz1</a></td>
                </tr>
```

my jquery function is
$('.table td a').click(function(){

```
 var cell_content = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();

 alert(cell_content);

});
```

if i click on the linkable column of the table, i need the whole row data in this function.

Comment: Did you try something? If so, provide your code please..

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this ?

```
$("#myTable tbody").on('click','tr', function(){
  var cell_content = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
});
```

Comment: This example if for a clickable row and retrieve the second cell content of the clicked row. Add some piece of your html table code.

Comment: @Spin0us....i have written the html and jquery function...pls help me regarding my problem

Comment: If you use the click event on the `.table td a` selector, then this will refer to this `a` element. So try `var cell_content = $(this).text();`.

Comment: but i need the whole row contents. suppose i click on the link1, then i would need all the three i.e xxxx,yyyy and zzzz

Comment: @Spin0us...Thank You so much